# Desempenho em aplicações com vários loops

Tags: javascript, desempenho

Ao pesquisar um pouco, achei vários códigos em Java para calcular o determinante de uma matriz. Passei um deles para javascript e ficou assim:

```
function determinant(A, N) {
  var det = 0;
  if (N == 1) {
    det = A[0][0];
  } else if (N == 2) {
    det = A[0][0] * A[1][1] - A[1][0] * A[0][1];
  } else {
    det = 0;
    for (var j1 = 0; j1 < N; j1++) {
      var m = [];
      for (var k = 0; k < (N - 1); k++) {
        m[k] = [];
      }
      for (var i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        var j2 = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < N; j++) {
          if (j == j1)  continue;
          m[i - 1][j2] = A[i][j];
          j2++;
        }
      }
      det += Math.pow(-1.0, 1.0 + j1 + 1.0) * A[0][j1] * determinant(m, N - 1);
    }
  }
  return det;
}
```

Está praticamente a mesma coisa. Ele funciona e calcula o determinante normalmente. Porém, quando a matriz passa da ordem 12x12, tanto no front-end quanto no back-end, com o nodejs, a aplicação demora muito para calcular  resultado. Quando calcula.

Sei que o motivo disso são os vários loops, além de ser uma função "recursiva", que se executa dentro de si mesma várias vezes.

Contudo, ao testar o [Math.js](http://mathjs.org/) para calcular o determinante, este independentemente da ordem da matriz, seja 30x30, calcula o resultado em menos de 1s. Dando uma olhada no [código dele](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.2.1/math.js) para o determinante, achei isso:

```
function _det (matrix, rows, cols) {
    if (rows == 1) {
      return object.clone(matrix[0][0]);
    }else if (rows == 2) {
      return subtract(
          multiply(matrix[0][0], matrix[1][1]),
          multiply(matrix[1][0], matrix[0][1])
      );
    }else{
      var compute_mu = function (matrix) {
        var i, j;
        var mu = new Array(matrix.length);
        var sum = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < matrix.length; i++) {
          sum = add(sum, matrix[i][i]);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
          mu[i] = new Array(matrix.length);
          mu[i][i] = unaryMinus(sum);
          for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            mu[i][j] = 0;
          }
          for (j = i + 1; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            mu[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
          }
          if (i+1 < matrix.length) {
            sum = subtract(sum, matrix[i + 1][i + 1]);
          }
        }
        return mu;
      };
      var fa = matrix;
      for (var i = 0; i < rows - 1; i++) {
        fa = multiply(compute_mu(fa), matrix);
      }
      if (rows % 2 == 0) {
        return unaryMinus(fa[0][0]);
      } else {
        return fa[0][0];
      }
    }
}
```

O código não é muito diferente de alguns outros exemplos que vi, mas como ele consegue ter um ganho de desempenho tão incrível?

É alguma especificidade do próprio código? Ou o uso de várias funções externas a esse bloco? Ou ainda a organização como um todo?

Confesso que fiquei me questionando sobre a performance dessa lib, muito boa por sinal. Agradeço qualquer explicação. Desde já, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

A principal diferença é a função recursiva, isso que dá uma grande matada no desempenho.

Resumidamente, a math.js já é bem optimizada, por isso não vale a pena reescrever as suas funções, a não ser por motivo de estudo.